# how can i install typescript

Tags: typescript, macos, installation

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/a/.npm/_logs/2023-11-08T05_58_43_501Z-debug-0.log

i tride to write "npm i -g typescript" but it return me error

Comment: What part of the error message specifically is unclear?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue as it's stated in the error message.
The problem is that npm doesn't have permission to write to the directory that it's trying to.

You can find the solution here in the npm documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

I would use the recommended solution which is to reinstall npm via a version manager.

Here are some popular tools you can use:

- NVM: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
- N: https://github.com/tj/n
- FNM: https://github.com/Schniz/fnm
- VOLTA: https://github.com/volta-cli/volta
- ASDF: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf